# How do I implement an addWaste method which adds the specific waste produced by each of my animals when they eat?

Tags: java

I have an enclosure which contains a range of animals of different types(e.g. Lion, Tiger). Each type of animal eats their own specific food and each specific food has a specific health value and waste value. Within this enclosure class I have a method called addWaste which will add the specific waste value that each animal produces when they eat their specific food. How should I implement this method? Here is where I have my food objects with their health and waste value:

```
public class Food {
     int healthGain;
     int wasteGain;
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Food steak = new Food();
         steak.healthGain = +3
         steak.wasteGain = 4
     }
}
```

For example, my lion eats steak, so when the lions in my enclosure eat they should add 4 waste to the enclosure. This method needs to be general as I have a range of animals in my enclosure each with their own food.

In my abstract animal class I have an eat() method which feeds the animal if this helps.

Also here I have specified what each animal can eat in their own respective constructor as follows:

```
super(new String[]{"steak", "celery"}) //it is stored as an array of strings
```

Here is my eat method in my animal class

```
public class Animal {
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("This animal is now eating");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show more code like Animal class etc.

Comment: Does the waste added by a steak depend on who is eating the steak? Will a lion produce more waste than a dog per steak eaten? Your enclosure class is missing in the whole picture.

Comment: Nope the waste value is assigned to each food not each animal.

Comment: can anyone help? I can provide more info if needed